# Show paper-spinner in front of app-toolbar

Tags: polymer-2.x

need some best advise on how to achieve load/busy status. In my PWA in index.html I have

```
  <body>
<paper-toast id="toast" text="Hi, welcome!"></paper-toast>
<paper-spinner id="working" class="mainSpinner" active></paper-spinner>
<my-app></my-app>
<noscript>
  Please enable JavaScript to view this website.
</noscript>
```

my-app element has typical app layout as per Polymer Starter Kit. app-toolbar, app-drawer etc. I programmatically turn the active flag of spinner at start of loading and turn it off at end of loading any element or data.

The issue I am facing is the spinner is hidden behind the app-toolbar. If I change the spinner active flag to true it is not shown.

Any idea how I can get the spinner on top of all the elements in the app-toolbar?

I tried putting CSS of the spinner with z-index: -1 but no help. The app-toolbar gets the whole view and in dev tools I can see the spinner is active but tucked behind the app-toolbar hence not visible.

Comment: I think you should set it `z-index:3 or more` of `spinner` insteed `-1`. Or you may move at middle of page with css instead at head of page.

Comment: Awesome ...! it worked. Thanks a ton Hakan. Is z-index 3 greater than z-index -1? looks like w.r.t priority

Comment: Oh man... now the issue is that with z-index 3 the menu tap or click behaviour is unresponsive and at times slow. I had to click 10-15 times on app-toolbar components to get it clicked. I changed it to z-index 1, but still the same issue.

Comment: A han.. its an issue with CSS positioning.         position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
        padding-top: 3vh;   .... I used this setting in the paper-spinner to bring it to center of the screen. It causes unresponsive behaviour in app-toolbar elements e.g. clicks/taps on hamburger icon